# How to create a multipart rectangle with custom cell heights?

Tags: tikz-pgf, multipart-node

I want to create a multipart rectangle with customizable cell-heights. The closest I could come to in the [documentation](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.rectangle:split) of a multipart rectangle was being able to customize the height of the empty part of a rectangle (drawn below).

So for the picture below made with the following code block how, would I customize the cell heights of the cells containing `WB`, `EX` and `M` to something like, say, 1cm, 2cm, and 3cm respectively?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw,rectangle split,
      rectangle split parts=4,
      rectangle split empty part height=3cm,
      rectangle split part fill={red!50, green!50, blue!50, yellow!50}] at (0,1)
    {WB\nodepart{two}EX\nodepart{three}M\nodepart{four}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Not very easily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=rectangle+split+height). Where should the text be inside the higher cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `matrix` instead of a `multipart` node. You need to fix a general width for all nodes to keep it uniform, but every node can be as tall as needed.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[matrix of nodes, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes={draw, minimum width=9mm},
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=red!50, minimum height=1cm}},
        row 2/.style={nodes={fill=green!50, minimum height=2cm}},
        row 3/.style={nodes={fill=blue!50, minimum height=3cm}},
        row 4/.style={nodes={fill=yellow!50, minimum height=3cm}},
        ]{WB\\EX\\M\\~\\};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works nicely. Do each of the cells also have (N/S/E/W) anchors so that I can use them as terminal points for lines coming in from other points of the diagram?

Comment: See the chapter about Shape library, Shapes with multiple text parts, section Shape rectangle split, which provides a drqwing of all anchor points of this shape. Right before 71.7 Callout shapes.

Comment: @smilingbuddha. Yes, every node is independent and you can use its anchors. You need to assign a name to the `matrix`  and each inner node can be referenced by `matrix_name-row_num-column_num`. See sections "20 Matrices and alignment" and "59 Matrix library"

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**

- Original answer was misleading. It doesn't work as was advertised :-(.
- In the `tikz` package manual, page 820, is noted

> When split vertically, the rectangle split will meet any `minimum width` requirements, but any
> `minimum height` will be ignored. Conversely when split horizontally, `minimum height` requirements
> will be met, but any `minimum width` will be ignored. In addition, `inner sep` is applied to every part
> that is used, so it cannot be specified independently for a particular part.

- So, you need an another way to reproduce desired result. One is given in the nice  answer @Ignasi, another can be get by use of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec=c,
                 rows = {belowsep+=-0.3ex}, % if in cells are used only capital letters
                 row{1} = {8mm, bg=red!50}, 
                 row{2} = {16mm,green!50}, 
                 row{3} = {4mm,blue!50}, 
                 row{4} = {24mm,yellow!50}
                 } 
WB      \\   
EX      \\
M      \\
        \\
    \end{tblr} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Above table code can be inserted in `tikz` node, if needed:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] {<tblr code>};
\end{tikzpicture}
```